# Disable hover on scroll to prevent browser repaint

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a hover effect on a list of div, the css is:

```
.product:hover {
  background-color: #f6f6f7;
  border-left-color: #f6f6f7 !important;
  border-right-color: #f6f6f7 !important;
  outline: 10px solid #f6f6f7;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

I want this hover effect to not be triggered when the user is scrolling the page, to not force the browser to repaint/reflow.

So I tried:

```
doc = $(document)
doc.scroll(->
  $('.product').unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave')
)
```

But it doesn't seem to work, when I scroll the hover effect is still triggered. Any idea why? Or how I have achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this in your css style page

`.disable-hover {
  pointer-events: none;
}`

You have to do is add the .disable-hover class to the body when you begin to scroll. This then allows the users cursor to pass through the body and thus disable any hover effects.

```
var body = document.body,timer;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
   clearTimeout(timer);
  if(!body.classList.contains('disable-hover')) {
    body.classList.add('disable-hover')
  }
   timer = setTimeout(function(){
    body.classList.remove('disable-hover')
  },500);
}, false);
```

Add this script and execute it will works:-

Comment: It will work in non IE browser? Pointer Events was first introduced by IE and I think Chrome still does not support it.

Comment: Hopefully you have no IE 8,9, or 10 users http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

```
document.body.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
```

when scroll event is triggered. Detailed docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).

Comment: To the downvoter: this is a proven [technique](http://www.thecssninja.com/css/pointer-events-60fps) so I don't understand the reason of downvoting. You can google it yourself typing "pointer events none performance"

Answer (score 0):

CSS hover has nothing to do with JavaScript events.

If you want to do what you are after, you will need to do it by adding/removing a class onscroll

```
var scrollTimer;
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if(scrollTimer) window.clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
    $("body").removeClass("effect");
    scrollTimer = window.setTimeout( function()
        $("body").removeClass("effect");
    }, 100);
});
```

and the CSS

```
.effect .product:hover {
  background-color: #f6f6f7;
  border-left-color: #f6f6f7 !important;
  border-right-color: #f6f6f7 !important;
  outline: 10px solid #f6f6f7;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

and PS: using important is BAD practice